# External properties file outside the war in GWT

Tags: gwt, properties

In my gwt application, I want to create an external file config.properties or config.xml. It must be outside the war file!

How can I do?

Thanks
Manolo

Comment: Please, be more precise. What do you need that external file for? And more important: how do you want to read that file?